# How to generate dynamic forms in PHP with all PHP form input types

Tags: php, mysql

How to create a dynamically generated form using PHP mySQl, for inserting or updating data in/of a particular table?

Comment: You want people to teach you how to program in 10 minutes?

Comment: "Dynamically" based on what? You mean something like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)?

Comment: Wait what??? Could you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate FORM that reflects MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968083/how-to-generate-form-that-reflects-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create your own form to allow you to modify MySQL databases. Code for this has already been written. See something like PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Take [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.form.html), add a little of [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.db.html), add salt and sugar, mix and then bake.