# How to generate FORM that reflects MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate HTML form based on MySQL table field. The generated input should reflect the type of the MySQL column, e.g. VARCHAR = text, TEXT = textarea, ENUM = checkbox,  SET = radio, etc.

Comment: @dm03514 , wow , you managed recommend one of the worst php frameworks .. and an ancient version at that.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of Lib is not available
But ya you can do it by making one table in your database that conatains details about form and retrive it and make HTML code dynamically

Comment: May be this link will helpfull to you, http://www.highdots.com/forums/macromedia-dreamweaver/create-php-form-mysql-table-268971.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step problem.

1. First you need to analyse the database table. You can get column names, type, etc. using [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html).
2. You need to generate the form based on the retrieved information.

Generating form can be as simple as iterating the array received from `SHOW COLUMNS` query and building HTML along the iteration, or using existing form generation libraries, e.g. [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.html) or [Dora](https://github.com/gajus/dora).

Depending on your needs, there is existing software for reflecting and manipulating the whole database, e.g. [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Furthermore, some frameworks provide means of reflecting the whole model (i.e. database table) in a form for CRUD operations, e.g. [Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).